# Metric pattern analysis for troubleshooting

Tags: java, python, go, data-analysis, metrics

When I troubleshoot some site issues, I need to check many metrics like CPU, memory, application metrics and so on. generally, I want to know the following items automatically (without checking all the metrics one by one by human) :

1. How many metrics have spikes during that time.
2. if metric X has the same pattern with metric Y
3. if metric X has some periodicity characters.

for item 1 and 2,  I think I can get it by calculating some change rate.  for item 3, I have no idea so far.

my questions here are:

1. do we have some library already which can be used here, language (Go, Java, Python is ok).
2. do you have any suggestion for requirement 3.

=====

More background here:

I have a Prometheus(a monitor system) setup already, but my issue is I want to analyze these metrics automatically.  For example:
User input:
Here are 1000 time-serial data and I have an issue on time 1 to time 2, I see metrics X has spiked during that time. 
Program output:
item 1/2/3 above.

I just have some issue during implement the program.

Comment: https://prometheus.io/

Comment: Thanks @Peter,  but that's not what I want now, please see my edited version.

Comment: https://github.com/etsy/skyline used to do this. It was intended for statsd and is no longer maintained, but perhaps it helps your googling efforts. Elasticsearch has something similar now (they call it machine learning) -- that is part of the commercial subscriptions though.

Comment: this is exactly what I want.  thank you.   I will search for a implemention for prometheus or an implemention with Python / Go /Java.  skylink is Python code but oculus is Ruby.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need some monitoring & analytic services like:

DataDog: https://www.datadoghq.com/

Librato: https://www.librato.com/

etc...

Or a self hosted infrastructure to run Graphite

(https://github.com/hopsoft/docker-graphite-statsd) or similar tools.